# How to return custom type from VBA function

Tags: excel, vba

I want to return a custom defined type from a VBA function. When I run the following code I get a error "Error on line:16 - type mismatch". I don't really understand what is going wrong.

```vb
Type FullName
    FirstName As String
    LastName As String
End Type

Sub Main 
Dim fullName As FullName
fullName = GetName()

MsgBox fullName.FirstName &" "& fullName.LastName

End Sub

Function GetName() As FullName
    Dim temp As FullName
    temp.FirstName = "John"
    temp.LastName = "Doe"

    Set GetName = temp

End Function
```

Comment: Could you try [GetName = temp] instead of [Set GetName = temp]

Comment: I tried it but same result

Comment: I've opened a new Excel, created a new Module, pasted your code, and checked that fails. Then quit the "Set". And it runs ok.

Comment: Oke, I'm running it in the Rumba Scripting Engine. So maybe thats the problem

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
Function GetName() As fullName
    Dim temp As fullName
    temp.FirstName = "John"
    temp.LastName = "Doe"

    With temp
        GetName.FirstName = .FirstName
        GetName.LastName = .LastName
    End With

End Function
```

But `GetName = temp` should be working as well

Comment: Now i get "Error on line:20-     GetName__.FirstName = .FirstName". I am running this code in Rumba Script engine for the Rumba Mainframe emulator. But this is just using VBA and some extra commands

Comment: Sorry I do not have Rumba Script engine and assumed you use this code within excel and its vba engine as indicated by the tags. This is a different story then.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I made it work, removing the `Set()` at the function:

```
Option Explicit

Type FullName

    FirstName As String
    LastName As String

End Type

Sub Main()

    Dim myFullName As FullName
    myFullName = GetName()
    Debug.Print myFullName.FirstName & " " & myFullName.LastName

End Sub

Function GetName() As FullName

    Dim temp As FullName
    temp.FirstName = "John"
    temp.LastName = "Doe"
    GetName = temp

End Function
```

The `myFullName` is introduced, in order to differentiate between the type `FullName` and the variable with the same name. In C#, I would have used `fullName` and `FullName`, but in VBA this "luxury" is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

PLease Give try on this

```
 Public Type FullName

   FirstName As String
   LastName As String

  End Type

Function GetName() As FullName

   Dim temp As FullName

       temp.FirstName = "John"
       temp.LastName = "Doe"

       GetName = temp

 End Function
```